# In Angular, is there a way for a second table to fill out depending on what you select in the first table?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have two tables. The first table is a list of groups. Each of those groups have sessions attached to them, which is what the second table is going to fill out with. What I want to happen is when the user clicks on a group from the first table, the second table right next to it fills with the correct sessions associated with that group.

Here is how my tables are set up:

```
<div>
    <h1>Manage Workflows</h1>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id = "groups">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Group</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                  

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table" id = "sessions">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Session</th>
                    <th scope="col" id = "trigger">Next Trigger</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you show the data model of a `group`? I think you can simply bind the click event on the first table to a function that will update the `currentSession` defined in your .ts file to the session of the selected group. Then use this `currentSession` variable in your second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. You can display details in second table by clicking the row of the first table.

Add a click event to the row and filter the data according to the row id.

```
public onRowClick(id: number): void {
    this.tableTwo= this.rows.filter(row => row.id === id);
  }
```

solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-add-record-dshxfy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you! I realized after looking at your stackblitz that I had my data model set up wrong.